# ObjectMapper with and without mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, objectmapper

I have a controller ItemController.java in which I'm using objectmapper in logger.info
objectMapper.writeValueAsString("something");

In the controller unit test, I need to use the object mapper as
mockMvc.perform(post("/api/items").content(objectmapper.writeValueAsString("something"));

If i mock the object mapper,i get error in the test file, if i don't mock it I get the error in the controller.
How do I do it?

Comment: can you format your question a bit better? And also include all the files you think are relevant? Its hard to help you since you dont provide the actual code.

Comment: You don't need to mock the objectMapper. Show us what the controller endpoint looks like and show us the error you get